# How to create this type of dialog

Tags: android-layout

I want to create a layout like this. Please help me, how can I create a dialog like this?

[image: this is the sample image]

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: Actually i am unable to start in order to create this type of layout. please provide a reference throught which it could be done.

Comment: create that layout like how you create your activity layouts and call it on custom dialog.

Comment: try learning from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android and here some exercise https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/